# Why would an UpdatePanel stop working after a few minutes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

What aspects of the UpdatePanel are sensitive to time?

I have an UpdatePanel that works fine.  If I leave the page for a few minutes and come back, the UpdatePanel doesn't work.  Looking at firebug, I see that it sends the Request and gets a Response back.  However, the page itself doesn't update.  I'm not seeing any script errors either.  So far I haven't been able to identify any other factor than the passage of time.

Comment: UpdatePanels are complete hacks - if possible, I would recommend learning how to do Ajax without them. They may be *easy* but they are hardly a good way to do things. Just my opinion, of course. :P

Comment: I know perfectly well how to do Ajax without them, and I agree with the recommendation to avoid them.  :-)  In this case, I was dealing with "legacy" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your application domain recycled or your Session was lost.  Have you tried seeing what is being called on the server?  That'd be my suggestion on where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Firebug network monitoring if enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the session expired, causing it to send back data that no longer matches the page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a session expiring, it should be reproducible without the UpdatePanel -- go back to postback and see if it also happens that way.  You might even get a better idea of the error since it isn't potentially eaten by the JavaScript that the UpdatePanel runs underneath the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that if you have a TON of controls in your update panel, it can either timeout or refuse to work.  One time I had a gridview in an update panel with three ajax calendar controls in each row..  total of 2,000 records in the gridview..   updatepanel was none too happy

Comment: Probably because the UpdatePanel does nothing more than send everything in it back and forth. It's not pretty. In your case, with all those controls, you would probably be shifting several megabytes :)